# Troubleshoot AJAX connection

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla

I'm having an issue with my AJAX connection in Joomla.

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var results = $('#hidden').serialize();

    var url = '<php? echo JURI::base(); ?>index.php?option=com_mls&view=list&format=raw&' + results;

    $('#test').html(url); //Just to see that the string is working.

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(){
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('failure');
        }
    });

});
```

**Joomla model for `view=list`:**

```
function ListData()
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $sort = JRequest::getVar('sort');
    $pstart = JRequest::getVar('pstart');
    $plimit = JRequest::getVar('plimit');
    $hprice = JRequest::getVar('hprice');
    $lprice = JRequest::getVar('lprice');
    $city = JRequest::getVar('city');
    $zip = JRequest::getVar('zip');
    $bdrms = JRequest::getVar('bdrms');
    $bths = JRequest::getVar('bths');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $db->nameQuote('#__mls') . " WHERE 1=1 ";
    if ($zip != null || $city != null || $bdrms != null || $bths != null || $hprice != null || $lprice != null){
        $firstand = "AND ";
    }
    $clauses = array();
    if ($zip != null) {
        $clauses[] = "MSTZIP = " . $zip;
    }

            ... a bunch of IF statements for building query...

    $query .= $firstand . implode(" AND ", $clauses) . $orderby . $pages;

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $table = $db->loadRowList();

    return $table;
```

**Joomla View:**

```
function display($tpl = null)
{
    $model = &$this->getModel();
    $array = $model->ListData();
    $this->assignRef( 'disparray', $array );
    parent::display($tpl);
}
```

Run before I can walk, I'm just trying to get the AJAX to display `success`.  It's not.  I can't tell where the mistake is and can't get any error reporting to help me out.  Any AJAX/Joomla savvy folks lend a hand?

Comment: what is the result of the AJAX request? Check the XHR tab on the network inspector in Chrome

Comment: Open developer tools in whatever browswer you are using. In Chrome you can hit f12 or ctrl+shift+j. Go to network, click XHR to show only ajax requests. You will see if the request is being sent and what HTTP status code it is returning. First test the url for the AJAX call in a seperate browser. If it does not work then you need to check the server side service before the AJAX call will work.

Comment: Use your developer tools to watch the request / response cycle. It will show errors and other issues.

Comment: Since you're not posting anything you can just put the ajax request URL into a browser and see what you're getting back.

Comment: `<php? echo JURI::base(); ?>` is definitely not right. Please check your syntax. (hint: it's supposed to be `<?php`)

Comment: Is it showing a failure?  If so, try to get more information.  Use console.log to print out the details.  jQuery docs for an ajax error: error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)

Comment: Looks like it wasn't rendering the `<php? echo JURI::base(); ?>`, and/or that it's not needed.  Once that's removed I get `Status Code:500 View class not found [class, file]: mlsViewlist, C:\inetpub\wwwroot\clients\mgoode\components\com_mls\views\list\view.raw.php`

Comment: Ok, got it working.  Issue was with URL params and view class name.  ...anyone want credit for that answer?

Comment: @Plummer it would be better if u post the answer yourself. And if the problem was an inadvertent coding error on your side, us hud probably remove the question as it is irrelevant future people having similar issues.

Comment: The developer tools was really the answer I needed.  Before I didn't have a way to check that stuff, now I do and was able to drill down the problem from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to use developer tools to see where AJAX query string was trying to go.  After that, I was able to determine the correct URL and class that needed to be accessed in the URL string.

```
//Removed '<php? echo JURI::base(); ?>'
var url = 'index.php?option=com_mls&view=list&format=raw&' + results;
```

Credit to Sajjan for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
jQuery.post('index.php',{
                'option'    : 'com_mls',
                'controller': 'controllerName',
                'task'  : 'taskName',
                'format'    : 'raw',            
                'results'   :  results                        
            }).success(function(result) { 
               alert('success');
            }).error(function() { 
                alert('error');
            });
```

In the controller you could have whatever the function you want(taskName). If you have any issues let me know